# Как вставить собственный класс в БД

Tags: java, postgresql

Написал свой класс в postgres

```
create type person as
(
firstname varchar(255),
lastname varchar(255),
middlename varchar(255),
gender char,
birhtday date
)
```

Создал таблицу

```
create type library_reader as
(
reader person,
abonement_number varchar(255),
recording_date date
)
```

Какой способ можно использовать для добавления класса Person в таблицу?

PS Класс Person в java создал

Answer (score 0):

Также как обычно, создаем таблицу согласно правилам [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) используя новый:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id integer,
    man person  //ссылка на тип person
);
```